# Отключить title и breadcrumbs в шаблоне WordPress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Пишу дочернюю тему для Storefront (Woocommerce) в которой есть шаблон template-fullwidth.php. Если этот шаблон стоит на главной странице, то заголовка и хлебных крошек там нет, но если ставлю на обычную страницу - они появляются.

Мне нужно отключить заголовок и крошки только в шаблоне template-fullwidth, но не трогая шаблон по умолчанию. Полагаю, что это можно сделать через functions.php, подскажите, как?

Comment: "Пишу дочку" - это сильно :)

Answer (score 0):

В файле wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/storefront-template-functions.php есть строчка `if ( is_front_page() && is_page_template( 'template-fullwidth.php' ) )`

Нужно заменить на `if ( is_front_page() xor is_page_template( 'template-fullwidth.php' ) )`

Таким образом отключил обложку и заголовок, но остались хлебные крошки. Для них прописал в style.css `.page-template-template-fullwidth-php .storefront-breadcrumb { display: none }`

Comment: И при первом обновлении темы всё это слетит.

Comment: Пример как делать НЕНУЖНО.Как минимум 4 ошибки в действиях.

Comment: @fortavey естественно я добавил этот файл в свою тему, чтобы редактировать, просто не счёл нужным описывать это действие.

Comment: @SeVlad где ошибки и почему не нужно? Я думал это место для ответов на вопрос, а не для язвительных комментариев. Если знаете, как нужно, то напишите ответ.